# How to put file path of chromedrive on Eclipse

Tags: java, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can I use Selenium to run for Google Chrome on Mac OS?  I have put the code underneath but it is still giving me an error.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/STQRY/Document/Jay");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

ERROR:

> ".....The driver executable is a directory: /Users/STQRY/Document/Jay"

I've copied the path straight from the file when I right clicked and selected 'Copy File'.

Comment: "The driver executable is a directory" is pretty self explanatory? You are supposed to provide an executable, but you provided a directory!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little google search can tell you that.

1. Download the chrome_driver (chromedriver_mac32.zip ) from this link if you haven't already : https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/
2. Unzip it.
3. Provide the path as follows.

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Path/To/ChromeDriver/chromedriver_mac");`

Or

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/xyz/abc/chromedriver_mac_2.20");`

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Prior to doing the below step make sure that the downloaded zip file is unzipped first
Next provide the code as specified below,

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/STQRY/Document/Jay/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Hi. I've entered the codes you have suggested but it is still giving me the same error?  Is there anyway I can fix this?  I even tried the codes that AGill have given  me but still nothing.

Comment: Dont worry about it. I got it :)